# Split a nested XML string to get a string using parser

Tags: python, xml, parsing, text, xml-parsing

I have this string :

```
'<Section xml:space="preserve" HasTrailingParagraphBreakOnPaste="False" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"><Paragraph FontSize="11" FontFamily="Portable User Interface" Foreground="#FF000000" FontWeight="Normal" FontStyle="Normal" FontStretch="Normal" CharacterSpacing="0" Typography.AnnotationAlternates="0" Typography.EastAsianExpertForms="False" Typography.EastAsianLanguage="Normal" Typography.EastAsianWidths="Normal" Typography.StandardLigatures="True" Typography.ContextualLigatures="True" Typography.DiscretionaryLigatures="False" Typography.HistoricalLigatures="False" Typography.StandardSwashes="0" Typography.ContextualSwashes="0" Typography.ContextualAlternates="True" Typography.StylisticAlternates="0" Typography.StylisticSet1="False" Typography.StylisticSet2="False" Typography.StylisticSet3="False" Typography.StylisticSet4="False" Typography.StylisticSet5="False" Typography.StylisticSet6="False" Typography.StylisticSet7="False" Typography.StylisticSet8="False" Typography.StylisticSet9="False" Typography.StylisticSet10="False" Typography.StylisticSet11="False" Typography.StylisticSet12="False" Typography.StylisticSet13="False" Typography.StylisticSet14="False" Typography.StylisticSet15="False" Typography.StylisticSet16="False" Typography.StylisticSet17="False" Typography.StylisticSet18="False" Typography.StylisticSet19="False" Typography.StylisticSet20="False" Typography.Capitals="Normal" Typography.CapitalSpacing="False" Typography.Kerning="True" Typography.CaseSensitiveForms="False" Typography.HistoricalForms="False" Typography.Fraction="Normal" Typography.NumeralStyle="Normal" Typography.NumeralAlignment="Normal" Typography.SlashedZero="False" Typography.MathematicalGreek="False" Typography.Variants="Normal" TextOptions.TextHintingMode="Fixed" TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Ideal" TextOptions.TextRenderingMode="Auto" TextAlignment="Left" LineHeight="0" LineStackingStrategy="MaxHeight"><Run>Panneau de polystyrène expansé (PSE) ignifugé réalisant une fonction d’isolation thermique pour un\nm² de surface en assurant la résistance thermique de R = 3.55 K.m².W-1.</Run></Paragraph></Section>'
```

My goal is to extract `Panneau de polystyrène expansé (PSE) ignifugé réalisant une fonction d’isolation thermique pour un\nm² de surface en assurant la résistance thermique de R = 3.55 K.m².W-1.` so the text between `<run>` and `</run>`

I did it with regular expression but it doesn't work with some xml string so I tried with `xml.etree.ElementTree` but I didn't succeed to access the sting nested in `<run></run>`

How can I extract this text using XML parser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a simple way to get the data:

```
xmlstr = '<Section xml:space="preserve" HasTrailingParagraphBreakOnPaste="False" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"><Paragraph FontSize="11" FontFamily="Portable User Interface" Foreground="#FF000000" FontWeight="Normal" FontStyle="Normal" FontStretch="Normal" CharacterSpacing="0" Typography.AnnotationAlternates="0" Typography.EastAsianExpertForms="False" Typography.EastAsianLanguage="Normal" Typography.EastAsianWidths="Normal" Typography.StandardLigatures="True" Typography.ContextualLigatures="True" Typography.DiscretionaryLigatures="False" Typography.HistoricalLigatures="False" Typography.StandardSwashes="0" Typography.ContextualSwashes="0" Typography.ContextualAlternates="True" Typography.StylisticAlternates="0" Typography.StylisticSet1="False" Typography.StylisticSet2="False" Typography.StylisticSet3="False" Typography.StylisticSet4="False" Typography.StylisticSet5="False" Typography.StylisticSet6="False" Typography.StylisticSet7="False" Typography.StylisticSet8="False" Typography.StylisticSet9="False" Typography.StylisticSet10="False" Typography.StylisticSet11="False" Typography.StylisticSet12="False" Typography.StylisticSet13="False" Typography.StylisticSet14="False" Typography.StylisticSet15="False" Typography.StylisticSet16="False" Typography.StylisticSet17="False" Typography.StylisticSet18="False" Typography.StylisticSet19="False" Typography.StylisticSet20="False" Typography.Capitals="Normal" Typography.CapitalSpacing="False" Typography.Kerning="True" Typography.CaseSensitiveForms="False" Typography.HistoricalForms="False" Typography.Fraction="Normal" Typography.NumeralStyle="Normal" Typography.NumeralAlignment="Normal" Typography.SlashedZero="False" Typography.MathematicalGreek="False" Typography.Variants="Normal" TextOptions.TextHintingMode="Fixed" TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Ideal" TextOptions.TextRenderingMode="Auto" TextAlignment="Left" LineHeight="0" LineStackingStrategy="MaxHeight"><Run>Panneau de polystyrène expansé (PSE) ignifugé réalisant une fonction d’isolation thermique pour un\nm² de surface en assurant la résistance thermique de R = 3.55 K.m².W-1.</Run></Paragraph></Section>'
from xml.etree import cElementTree as ET
results = []
root = ET.fromstring(xmlstr)
for p in list(root):
 for r in list(p):
  print(r.text)
  results.append(r.text)
```

Result:

Panneau de polystyrène expansé (PSE) ignifugé réalisant une fonction d’isolation thermique pour un m² de surface en assurant la résistance thermique de R = 3.55 K.m².W-1.

If you run the code in a python interactive prompt, at the end you can use results:

```
>>> results
['Panneau de polystyrène expansé (PSE) ignifugé réalisant une fonction d’isolation thermique pour un\nm² de surface en assurant la résistance thermique de R = 3.55 K.m².W-1.']
>>> results[0]
'Panneau de polystyrène expansé (PSE) ignifugé réalisant une fonction d’isolation thermique pour un\nm² de surface en assurant la résistance thermique de R = 3.55 K.m².W-1.'
```

Comment: Thanks it works! I don't understand why the for loop return specifically this value. Can you explain please so I will be able to do it alone for the next time? :)

Comment: you can add a list (results) at the begin and instead of: print(r.text) do results.append(r.text). Every xml node with text content can be accessed as element.text. The first loop cycle over Paragraphs and the second, for every Paragraph, cycle over Runs. for every Run, it prints the text content of the <Run> tag. At the end, results will contains all the Runs text. If you've one, you can get it as results[0], outside the loops.